# I have to transform two time models into Laplace tranforms and then into transfer functions.

Tags: functions, laplace-transform

The mathematical model of the pitch motion is:
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=-20\,\frac{d\theta}{dt}-4\theta+5u,$$
where $\theta$ is the pitch angle to be controlled and $u$ is the control input, provided by the aerodynamic action of the movable fins.

The pitch angle is measured using an inclinometer. The manufacturer data sheet demonstrates that the instrument response to a step input can be modeled as a first order system with a time constant $\tau$ of $0.25$ seconds, and therefore its mathematical model is:
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=-\frac1\tau\,\theta+4.$$

For the first model I have $Y(s)=5/(s^2+20s+4)$
and for the second I have $Y(s)=4/(s+(1/\tau)).$

I am rather unsure if these are correct as I am not the best at Laplace transforms!

Comment: A few comments: please include any initial conditions you've been given. Your $Y(s)$ for the first model could only have been gotten if you have initial conditions. Secondly, you should check your signs: I get a $+20s$ in the denominator of the first model. Also: do you know what $u$ is?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i was not given any initial conditions but i just assumed they were 0? Yes sorry i put the wrong sign i got +20s as well. Regarding u, i only know from the question that it is the control input.

Comment: You cannot assume the initial conditions are zero, unless you have physical reasons for doing so. Can you assume that the original pitch and original pitch's angular velocity are zero? Maybe. By the way, in English, the pronoun "I" is always capitalized.

Comment: If the conditions are described as "perfect/ideal" can I assume they are zero? From now on I will capitalise my I's.

Comment: "Perfect/ideal" doesn't strike me as equivalent to zero initial conditions. It's ambiguous. I would think it better to keep those initial conditions in your LT, so they show up in the final answer.